# Remote dimming-lights only flutter

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I hooked up the following (see pic).  All was a success until I wanted to dim the lights and they just flutter.   From box I only had orange load wire and black tied to “onward” black.   I connected Blue, black, and white from fan/light to corresponding blue, black, and white from one side of the transmitter.   The red from other side of transmitter went to orange load from box.  The white from other side of transmitter went to the two blacks from box.  As long as I keep lights fully lit, no issues.  The fluttering happens from wall and remote.  Any idea how I can get lights to dim? Thank you.  [image: remote, switch, transmitter]

Comment: Are they CFL or LED?  Can you try putting an old style incandescent into ONE of the lamps and see if that fixes it?

Comment: Yes, what are you using for lightbulbs?

Comment: Bingo!!  I thought it came with incandescent, so I tried LED and same issue, but just now realized it came with LED’s.  AND  realized transmitter is for incandescent only.   I think for now, I’ll switch to incandescent bulbs.   Thanks again Harper and ThreePhase!!!!